# Setting authorization header in axios

Tags: http, reactjs, get, http-status-code-401, axios

I have been trying to make a GET request to the National Park Service API with axios and have tried several ways to set my API key in the request header to no avail. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "MY-API-KEY";
axios.get('https://developer.nps.gov/api/v0/parks?parkCode=yell')
.then((resp) => {
    console.dir(resp);
});
```

and

```
let config = {'Authorization': 'MY-API-KEY'};
axios.get('https://developer.nps.gov/api/v0/parks?parkCode=yell', config)
.then((resp) => {
    console.dir(resp);
});
```

and both return a 401. 
It works when I send the GET request in Postman, where I enter Authorization in the key field, and my API key in the value field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue is caused by CORS OPTIONS request in browser, which has nothing to do with axios. https://developer.nps.gov requires `Authorization` header in all HTTP request, including  OPTIONS. However, all custom HTTP headers will be excluded from OPTIONS, refer to https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0

The National Park Service API should not require `Authorization` header for OPTIONS request, but it does. Anyway, there is a workaround: make a forward-route in your own backend, accept the HTTP request from browser, retrieve data from https://developer.nps.gov in backend, and finally return it to browser.

Actually, send HTTP request with third party authorization key from browser is definitely not a good idea -- This design will expose your National Park Service API key to everyone who visit the page, which is certainly a dangerous thing.

---

Your first solution (config API key to axios default headers) is OK. I tried with my own API key and your URL, the response code is 200 OK.

For the second solution, the `config` object should be used as `headers` field in axios statement. The code would be:

```
axios.get('https://developer.nps.gov/api/v0/parks?parkCode=yell', {headers: config})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've done a bit more research and it appears that the reason for failure is due to the browser sending an OPTIONS preflight request without the authorization header. This comes back as 401 and thus the GET request is not performed. However, I have not been able to find a way around this. I get the following in the console: `OPTIONS https://developer.nps.gov/api/v0/parks?parkCode=yell 401 (OK)`

Comment: `localhost/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://developer.nps.gov/api/v0/parks?parkCode=yell. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
`

Comment: ah, that's because all custom HTTP headers will be excluded from CORS OPTIONS request. I'll update my answer to include the workaround.

Comment: BTW, I was using axios in Node.js environment, that's why I didn't meet the CORS problem.

Comment: Thank you!! It works! I really appreciate your help.