# AXIOS : Send Authorization header returns Error 401, Authorization Header missing

Tags: vue.js, authorization, axios

I came around [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014034/setting-authorization-header-in-axios) solution but this is not working for me.

Following is my code:

```
axios.post('http://myurl/api/login', {
  email: 'john@doe.com',
  password: '123456'
}, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  }
}).then(response => {
  if (response.data) {
    this.AuthToken = response.data.token
    console.log(this.AuthToken)
    axios.get('http://myurl/userdetails/:uid', {
      uid: 'D123'
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': this.AuthToken
      }
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.data) {
        // this.AuthToken = response.data
        console.log(response.data)
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('User Data response Error: ' + error)
    })
  }
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('Login Error: ' + error)
})
```

I'm getting token from the first POST Login API call. I used that toke to pass into another API call as Authentication token. But I get error: **Missing Authorization Headers**

Comment: Have you tried adding 'Bearer' in front of the token? https://security.stackexchange.com/q/108662

Comment: Yes I tried this before, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = this.AuthToken;
```

Comment: Don't forget, you might need something like:

    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + this.authToken;

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another header. "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "*".