# Error: Authorization header malformed when using Axios and JWT with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, next.js, axios, jwt

I am trying to register a user and somehow get the userdata using Axios and JWT with Wordpress. I am following from this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668099/axios-send-authorization-header-returns-error-401-authorization-header-missin?rq=4) Below is my code:

```
const signupdata = {
  username: loginFields.email,
  email: loginFields.email,
  password: loginFields.password
}
axios.post('http://nextjs-headless-wordpress.local/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', loginData)
  .then(res => {
    if (res.data) {
      console.log('authToken' + res.data.data.token);
      //axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = res.data.data.token;

      axios.post('http://nextjs-headless-wordpress.local/wp-json/wp/v2/users', signupdata, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          "Accept": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res.data.data.token
        }
      }).then(response => {
        if (response.data) {
          console.log(response.data)
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('User Data response Error: ' + error)
      })

    }
});
```

I was able to get the token in my first axios.post call, but I kept getting this error when I try to get the userdata

```
{success: false, statusCode: 403, code: 'jwt_auth_bad_auth_header', message: 'Authorization header malformed.', data: Array(0)}
```

I checked and it seems I am using the correct `token` when calling the axios.post to wordpress. Where in my code did I get wrong? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the token itself is even valid. You can use a tool like [this](https://lotsoftools.com/tools/jwt) to decode the token.

Specifically, you should make sure:

- The token is not actually malformed (there is a decoded token)
- The token is not expired
- If you know the secret key; verify its signature

I suspect that the issued token is wrong, possibly because an of incorrect environment variable or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think there can be many things that might help, and I'll mention a few of them. Hopefully, your problem will be solved!

First of all, try parsing the JSON response from the first `axios` post call and verify if the token is being extracted correctly!

```
const signupdata = {
  username: loginFields.email,
  email: loginFields.email,
  password: loginFields.password
}

axios.post('http://nextjs-headless-wordpress.local/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', loginData)
  .then(res => {
    if (res.data && res.data.token) {
      console.log('authToken' + res.data.token);

      axios.post('http://nextjs-headless-wordpress.local/wp-json/wp/v2/users', signupdata, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${res.data.token}`
        }
      }).then(response => {
        if (response.data) {
          console.log(response.data);
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('User Data response Error: ' + error);
      });

    }
  });
```

I wanted to point out that I added a check for `res.data.token` to ensure that the token actually exists in the response. It's always good to be sure about these things!

and instead of using `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, why not give `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` a try for the headers in your second axios post call? It might work better for you!

by the way, when you make the second axios post call, don't forget to verify that the authorization header is properly set. Remember, the format should be `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res.data.data.token'`. It's an important detail!

Another thing you could do is double-check if the token is correctly appended to the header. also, take a moment to make sure that the endpoint `'http://nextjs-headless-wordpress.local/wp-json/wp/v2/users'` is correct and accessible. It's always good to be thorough!

and have you heard about these popular plugins? `JWT Authentication for WP REST API` and `WP JWT Authentication` could be really useful for you. Just make sure you configure them correctly and check if they support the version of WordPress you're using.

If none of these suggestions work, don't worry! You can enable debugging mode in your WordPress installation to get more detailed error messages. Just add the following line to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

good luck !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a space in your Authorization header. The [correct format](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) is `Authorization: Bearer <token>`, but your code produces `Authorization: Bearer<token>`. Try this instead:

```js
axios.post( 'http://nextjs-headless-wordpress.local/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',loginData)
.then( res => {
        if(res.data){
            console.log('authToken: ' + res.data.data.token);
            //axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = res.data.data.token;

        axios.post('http://nextjs-headless-wordpress.local/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/users/me', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res.data.data.token
          }
        }).then(response => {
          if (response.data) {
            console.log(response.data)
          }
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log('User Data response Error: ' + error)
        })

        }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jack, it's still the same. I have edited my axios call, supplying a `signupdata` to be used for registering a user, but I get the same 403 error, only this time the message is 'Algorithm not allowed' but still a forbidden 403 error.

Comment: You can use nesting Axios calls and use async/await to better handle this scenario.
Like this
const response_data = await axios.post('http://nextjs-headless-wordpress.local/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', loginData);
const authToken = response_data.data.data.token;
const userDataResponse = await axios.post('http://nextjs-headless-wordpress.local/wp-json/wp/v2/users', signupdata, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    "Accept": "application/json",
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
  }
});

Comment: @TsukimotoMitsumasa It's not the same - you got a different error message. That is progress! Keep going and you will get it eventually. The other answers have good next steps to try.

Comment: @TsukimotoMitsumasa Some Googling makes me think it might be [this issue](https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth/issues/247) with an outdated plugin - there was a bug in the plugin that caused the "algorithm not allowed" error. I think it is unlikely that you are doing anything in your own code that would cause an invalid algorithm to be used, as you are not actually constructing the JWT yourself, but fetching it from the server.

Comment: Try updating or disabling your plugins, and see if that fixes the issue.