# Node + Express + Passport: req.user Undefined but works in Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

My issue is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434893/node-express-passport-req-user-undefined), all answers there didnt help me.

I'm using Passport.js with local strategy (passport-local-mongoose). 
The middleware below works on Postman but fails whenever I try from my React client.

```
exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.user) // undefined with react, but works from postman
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
}
```

Here's my app.js:

```
require('./handlers/passport');
app.use(cors())
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

handlers/passport.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

user.js (model):

```
...
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: 'email' });
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:7777/users/<id>';
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
};

axios.put(url, data, config)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Am I missing something? does passportLocal strategy means that I can't use with an API and a client like my example? Thanks :D

Comment: Show your code where you send request to the server in React app.

Comment: There's nothing different from a normal http call. I'm using axios.js without sending any headers, I already tried with 

const headers = { credentials: 'include' };

Comment: I'm not totally sure of how you're handling your token when you authenticate a user in your client. So, since you're using axios, you need to explicitly set your request authorization which you can include in the subsequent request. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014034/setting-authorization-header-in-axios)

Comment: Hey @Rowland, so what exactly I need to set in my Authorization header?

This is my first time using passport.js, I don't know what I should store as "token".

After my successful /login I can see the "set-cookie:" property as response headers, I can access it through document.cookie, sending it to the server in the subsequent request doesnt work too.

Answer (score 4):

So, after some time I could find an answer:

Server sends SetCookie header then the browser handle to store it, and then the cookie is sent with requests made to the same server inside a Cookie HTTP header.

I had to set `withCredentials: true` in my client. (axios.js)

```
const config = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
};

axios.put(url, { page: '123' }, config)
  .then(res => console.log('axios', res))
  .catch(err => console.log('axios', err));
```

Then I had CORS problems.

So I added this to my express server:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
      next();
  }
});
```

Comment: You are a life saver man. I was stuck here for 3 hours. you saved me.